# Remove "Wireless network is now connected..." notification on Win XP?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

Is there a way to remove the bubble that pops up each time Windows XP connects to a network?  I often use my laptop in a cafe where the network seems to come and go, and each time Windows (re)connects, it notifies me with a dialog box / bubble.  It's distracting and largely useless.  Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried right-clicking on the wireless indicator in the notification area, and looking for an option to not be notified?

Answer (score 4):

Answertips is right:

[image]

Comment: Someone edit either answer to have the image inline

Comment: I'd like to keep the icon...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to disable **Show icon in notification area when connected** from Network Connections for the Wireless network?

Comment: i'd +1 you if you had a screenshot of the checkbox :)

Comment: I'm giving you the +1.  Thank you!

Comment: So there is no way to show the icon, but hide this balloon, without hiding all balloons?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the tray icon, you can follow these instructions to knock off balloon tips in the notification area:

**[How do I disable balloon tips in the notification area in Windows XP or Vista?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307729)**

[Tweak UI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) (MS Powertoys) can do that as well.

Or use the VBS script provided at **[Kelly's Korner](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm)** to disable/enable balloon tips (11/L).